# "localhost is currently unable to handle this request" on using ssh2_connect command

Tags: php

I am using ssh2_connect command in php to connect to my remote server with the IP Address of the remote server, port no., username and password. Every time I run the code I get the error "localhost is currently unable to handle this request."

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using apache2 and php 7.2 on my ubuntu server.

```
<?php
    $connection = ssh2_connect('ip-address', 22);;

    if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password')) {
        echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
    } else {
        die('Authentication Failed...');
    }
?>
```

Comment: make sure that the [SSH2 PECL extension](http://php.net/book.ssh2) is installed and enabled.it's not part of standard php